# connection string between login with facebook in my website and sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am doing a poject webbsaite to upload photo , i fixed login with facebook , but my problem is how can i make a sql connection string in sql server MSSQL with the people that will visit my website and login with facebook account ???PLZ anyone knew ?

Comment: please give us detailed information about what you are trying to do. what have you tried anything so far ? Any code ?

Comment: Please provide more details. "how can i make a sql connection string in sql server MSSQL with the people that will visit my website" does not explain what exactly you are trying to achieve with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

i want to store facebook user token id , so when somebody login with facebook account to my website then i want to get and save the user id in my sql server . 
and here is my cod for the logging with facebook account in my website

```
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1407528266185362', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/http://localhost:44963/', // Path to your Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                    document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
                    document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
                })
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
    }
</script>
<div id="auth-status">
    <div id="auth-loggedout">
        <div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
    </div>
    <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
        Hej <b><span id="auth-displayname"></span></b><a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">Logga ut!</a><br />
        <b><span id="Email"></span></b>
        <br />
        <img id="profileImg" />
    </div>
</div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>Galleriet</h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <asp:Panel ID="ResponsePanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="closeImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="Content/delete1.png" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="closeImg_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <asp:Image ID="FullImage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ItemType="Galleriet.Model.ThumImgUrl" SelectMethod="Repeater1_GetData" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Item.FileUrl %>' CssClass='<%# FullImage.ImageUrl.EndsWith(Item.Name) ? "ActiveImg" : null %>'>
                    <asp:Image ID="ImageOne" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Item.ImgUrl %>' />
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" GroupingText="ladda upp bild.">
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="TheFileUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="<img src=Content/wrong.png /> Fel inträffade! Korrigera felet och försök igen." />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Det måste finna ett filnamn." ControlToValidate="TheFileUpload" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src=Content/wrong.png /> Giltiga filändelser är gif, jpg och png." ControlToValidate="TheFileUpload" ValidationExpression="^.*\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG)$" Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>


        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Ladda upp" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function showimagepreview(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var filerdr = new FileReader();
                  filerdr.onload = function (e) {
                      $('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                  filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
```

```
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://c-sharp-corner.blogspot.in/2012/06/social-share-buttons-in-aspnet.html" title="share on facebook">Click to share on facebook</a>
```